# Odoo 10 Accounting

Tags: odoo-10

Can anyone point me to where I can find the Model and Form View details to Accounting->Aged Payable and Aged Receivable Reports, I need to put a button in the header. I am new with Odoo and I can't find the details like I do with the other Models.Thank you in advance.

Comment: what you want in main menu can't understand well so can you describe ?

Comment: I want to put an Expand/Collapse button in the header of Aged Receivable and Aged Payable Reports. I know how to make a button I just don't know what is the external id of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Accounting Module then go to reports.

```
Accouting> Reports > Aged Payable and Aged Receivable Reports
```

This is the path to the reports that you have asked. Hope this will help you :)

Thanks

Abhay S